# WebDriver's sendKeys() method does not fill out "(" in input-field when using Firefox 14

Tags: firefox, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys, input-field

I'm using webdriver to fill out a input-field and for some reason all text is inserted but "(".

```
findElementById("elementId").sendKeys("This is a text"); -> This is a text
findElementById("elementId").sendKeys("method().getName()"); -> method).getName)
findElementById("elementId").sendKeys("(((((((("); -> 
findElementById("elementId").sendKeys("(((aaaa"); -> aaaa
```

The error appears to occur only in Firefox 14. When we run the test against Firefox 12, it works fine.

Any idea why this odd behavior?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this issue using Firefox 15 and the Python webdriver Bindings on Ubuntu 12.10. But everything worked as it should. Maybe try the new version.

Comment: I updated my Firefox to version 15 without success. I'm using Java. We have faced the problem on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Windows 7 and Mac Os Mountain Lion 10.8

Comment: Seems that the problem is with jQuery UI Auto-complete plugin. For some odd reason it interpret "(" as "ENTER".

Comment: Great you found the reason. And thanks for letting us know!

Comment: (Maybe even post it as accepted answer, so that it is visible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the problem is with jQuery UI Auto-complete plugin. For some odd reason it interpret "(" as "ENTER".